# JavaScript not correctly encoding and decoding the characters

Tags: javascript, string, base64, decoding

I have the below code that is decoding incorrectly.

```
btoa(atob("nirajan")) //Output: "nirajak="
```

but this below code works perfectly

```
btoa(atob("niranjan")) //Output: "niranjan"
```

Can somebody explain what is wrong with the first part and difference between the two code examples.

PS: Tested on Chrome

Comment: are you sure you don´t want atob(btoa()) instead?

Comment: @juvian btoa would expect base64 input.

Comment: @Mic — No, `btoa` takes binary input and gives base64 output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) *encodes* the string and [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) *decodes* the string.

So you have your methods backwards. First, encode with `btoa` with the inner function, then, decode with `atob` on the outer function.

```
atob(btoa('Hello world!')); // returns 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: what do `b` and `a` in `btoa` mean? Normally one would assume it's `base64 to ascii` (decoder) but infact it's actually the reverse. It's so unintuitive.

Comment: Good question. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) page, I think it is "**B**inary to base64 **A**SCII." I agree, that is pretty confusing and seems a bit backwards. In our case, our "binary" data is just a string, so that seems to be where the confusion comes in.

Comment: Found more information here - https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/webappapis.html#atob

Yep, it says: "NOTE: In these APIs, for mnemonic purposes, the "**b**" can be considered to stand for "**binary**", and the "**a**" for "**ASCII**". In practice, though, for primarily historical reasons, both the input and output of these functions are Unicode strings."

Comment: thanks for digging :) alas, i'll have to put a INVERT in my head when thinking about these two functions :P